# Run aspx site backed by MySQL on Azure

Tags: asp.net, mysql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm completely new on Azure, I have a aspx.net site that talks to a MySQL db, I would like to run both, site and db on Azure, what would be the bext way to do so? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options here depending on the load and bandwidth you expect, what kind of service level agreement you need, the amount of control you want over the application, etc.  Let me start by saying you can try all these options out - free - for 90 days with a [trial account](http://aka.ms/GetAzureTrial).

The easiest (and cheapest) entry point would be [Windows Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/)  Depending on your bandwidth requirements, [you could actually run this completely free](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/) (along with a MySQL DB on Azure for a year).   Web Sites are shared infrastructure, though there is a higher tier (reserved) which can give you a more consistent availability and throughput.  At this time, Web Sites are in a preview mode, so there is no SLA.  [For a walkthrough see this tutorial.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/)

Via [Windows Azure Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/cloud-services/) (Platform-as-a-Service) you could deploy your ASP.NET site to a Web Role and use the [ClearDB offering](https://www.cleardb.com/store/azure) (their free offering is what you get as part of Web Sites above).  Cloud Services give you a lot more flexibility to scale your application and couple it with other enterprise-grade services in the cloud, and it's covered by a 99.95 SLA. You are [charged an hourly rate](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/cloud-services/) depending on the configuration and number of virtual machines running your app.  With Cloud Services, you'd use Visual Studio and simply deploy your application as a Cloud Service - the management of the underlying resources (virtual machines, etc.) is handled for you by Windows Azure - hence "Platform-as-a-Service"

Lastly there's the newly released [Virtual Machines](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/) option (Infrastructure-as-a-Service) where you take complete control of the VM that hosts your application.  Unlike, Cloud Services you own your VM, so it's up to you to apply operating system patches, install your application and any other ancillary software, and apply any necessary configuration steps. It's a lot of power with a lot of responsibility. In general, I'd only consider Virtual Machines for your scenario if there's a specific technical reason Cloud Services won't work. For the MySQL side, you could also use a Virtual Machine to run MySQL on your own, but again you would own the administration of that service, have to apply patches, clear logs, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I would have expected to be able to simply drop my web folder on Azure, the first 2 options I'm not sure they will work for me as they require to create new projects on Visual Studio and so on... However, the option for Virtual Machines sounds good as I can replicate my local environment on the Virtual Machine. I just only want to have a case study of my site running on Azure for now.

Comment: If you're building ASP.NET apps now then option 1 and 2 are really the way to go.  Neither requires creating new projects, you can use web deploy.